# using VB.net with itextsharp to create PDF/A-3

Tags: vb.net, itext, pdfa

I'm successfully using VB.Net with itextsharp to save file as PDF but when I try to produce PDF/A-3, I have no idea on what function and parameter to use.

I can only find the sample code for C# but when trying to paste the code and convert to VB.net, it does not work.

Any example of VB.net from experience developer is very appreciated.

Comment: You have tried to convert the code to VB.NET. Please add your VB.NET code to your question, even if it does not yet compile.

Comment: ... and reference the C# code you started with.